# How to insert text or token into the token stream in the lexer?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I would like to insert a token right before EOF during lexing. Is this possible with antlr3 (C-target)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the nextToken() function and return your virtual token under the specific condition you have. Without going to the runtime I see no way to do this, however.

Comment: Overriding is not possible because I'm using the C-target. I did however modify the nextToken() method to emit a new token once EOF is reached. Thanks.

Comment: Overriding in the C target *is* possible. It's done by replacing default function pointers by your own. In this case see ANTLR3_TOKEN_SOURCE_struct where the nextToken() function pointer is set. Replace this with your own. This is similar to setting your own error handlers etc. Btw. if my answer solved your problem please accept it.